# I have a variable with another variable within its name. How do I change it into a session variable?

Tags: php, session, variables

Basically what the title says. I know how to make a normal variable into a session variable `($_SESSION['var'])`, but not when it contains another var

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["uname"] = "Tyler";

if (isset($_SESSION["coins{$uname}"])) 
{
    echo "$_SESSION["uname"] : $_SESSION["coins{$uname}"]";
}
elseif ($_SESSION["uname"] == "LOut")
{
    $_SESSION["coins{$uname}"] = "0";
    echo "Log In";
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["coins{$uname}"] = 500;
    echo "$_SESSION["uname"] : $_SESSION["coins{$uname}"]";
}
?>
```

I've tried the following:

```
$_SESSION['{coins.$uname}']
$_SESSION['coins.$uname']
$_SESSION['coins.$_SESSION['uname']']
```

And I don't remember if I've tried anything else.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Tyler.  When you post code, try to provide only the relevant parts. I edited to remove all the html, css etc that isn't relevant to this problem.

Comment: You should specify if your problem is CREATING or ECHOING the session variable. People are trying to help you with CREATING, but there is also a syntax error when you try to echo the session variables: echo "$_SESSION["uname"] : $_SESSION["coins{$uname}"]";.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that it's not working, but you haven't specified if setting it or echoing it is the problem: Based on your original, unedited question, there are two problems:

### Setting the session variable

This should work:

```
$_SESSION["coins{$uname}"] = 500;
```

If you can't get it to work, try breaking it down into a couple of steps.

```
$tempname = 'coins'.$uname;
$_SESSION[$tempname] = 500;
```

Now test it.

### Outputting the session variable

`echo $_SESSION["coins{$uname}"];` or `echo $_SESSION[$tempname];`

*Edit*

There is a syntax error in your code:

```
echo "$_SESSION["uname"] : $_SESSION["coins{$uname}"]";
```

You are closing your starting quote (") by mistake when you try to open quotes for ["uname"]. Try:

```
echo "$_SESSION['uname'] : ".$_SESSION["coins{$uname}"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Double-quotes are the ones you want.

```
$_SESSION["coins.$uname"]
```

Or

```
$_SESSION["coins.{$_SESSION['uname']}"]
```

Either of those should work just fine.

**Explanation:**
Single quotes will encapsulate a string as-is. Double quotes will actually parse the string and replace any variables contained within. Sometimes, a variable will not be clearly identifiable within the string, for example:

```
print "This is the $numberth time"; 
// Expected: 'This is the 50th time'
// Actual:   'This is the  time'
```

In this case you can use curly braces to clearly separate a variable, ie:

```
print "This is the {$number}th time";
```

As a rule of thumb, I usually wrap any object attribute or array value within curly braces, ie:

```
print "This is the {$this->number}th time";
print "This is the {$time['number']}th time";
```

Comment: Explanation and examples. +1

Comment: Used both of those (changed the 'uname' in the second one to have double quotes as well, since I assumed you just forgot that), and neither worked. Thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: No, the single quotes are correct within the double quotes - otherwise it breaks the string. If it's still causing issues, you can try creating a separate variable name variable, ie $coinsUname = 'coins.' . $_SESSION['uname']; $_SESSION[$coinsUname]; and seeing if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$_SESSION["coins{$uname}"]`

The difference is...

1) Double quotes when using the `brace` syntax

2) I'm assuming your using the dot `.` character for concatenation here? You dont need it if you use the brace syntax...

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
    $$coins = "Tyler";

    if (isset($$coins)) 
    {
    echo "uname : {$$coins}";
    }
    elseif ($$coins == "LOut")
    {
    $$coins = "0";
    echo "Log In";
    }
    else
    {
    $$coins = 500;
    echo "$uname : $$coins";
    }
    ?>

    <br>
    <a href="test.php">Test</a>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>
```

so your session will be

```
$_SESSION['$$coins']
```

This is the way i handle variable variables...

Dins